# The Rails Way for Reducing HTML Duplication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, dry

In my .html.erb file, I have a lot of lines of information to display. I am accomplishing this with a simple: (using blueprint css)

```
<% for event in @user.events %>
<div class="span-5 border">Descriptor:</div> <div class="span-5 last"><%=h event.foo%></div><br/>
<% end %>
```

How can I make it so that I can call some function that would render the information part and I would pass it just the Descriptor (a string literal) and the method for event ("foo" in this case).

I'm new to rails and I think this could be accomplished using a partial render, but I'm not entirely sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
render :partial => 'event', :collection => @user.events, :locals => {:descriptor => 'descriptor', :method => 'foo'}
```

If you're using a recent version of rails this shorthand version will also work:

```
render @user.events, :locals => {:descriptor => 'descriptor', :method => 'foo'}
```

In your partial

```
<div class="span-5 border"><%= descriptor -%></div> <div class="span-5 last"><%=h event.send(method) %></div><br/>
```

Comment: What would the _event.erb look like?

Comment: Hi Reti. Sorry for incomplete description, I've edited answer. This should work but let me know if not.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. I put in 

    `<%= render @user.events, :locals => {:descriptor => 'descriptor', :method => 'foo'} %>`

under the `<% for event in @user.events %>` and the partial you said in the correct place, but now it's saying 'descriptor' is undefined. I also tried the other render you provided, but it says that event is undefined. What's going on?

Comment: In the second case it's not finding the partial file which probably means it's not in the same directory or named differently - it should be named with a prefix underscore - "event.html.erb" . The first case, you should remove the for loop; the render @user.events it to be an array and iterates over it. As to why descriptor is undefined I'm not sure but try removing the loop and see what happens. I assume descriptor is just a string being passed as in the example?

Comment: "_event.html.erb" rather... Also the rails guide is really good - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use partials.
Its advantage that it makes code DRY.Also you can replace the particular div by Ajax callback.
Save the partials with prefix '_' on file name like _test.rhtml

```
render :partial => 'test', :layout => false
```